# Unity won't Instantiate() outside of Start(), even though code is the same

Tags: unity, websocket, socket

I am trying to add a gameobject to my game using a socket connection. I have a SocketHandler class, which simply connects to my NodeJS socket server, which can also call a method on another class, which will add a new gameobject to the game. Here is how it basically works:

```
void Start () {
    GameObject car = Instantiate(CarGameObject);
    car.transform.parent = this.transform;
    car.GetComponent<TestCar>().text.text = "Volkswagen";
}
```

This works fine and it adds the gameobject to the game upon starting. However, if I do something like this in my SocketHandler, it doesn't work:

```
var addCar = new AddCar();
socketio.On("addCar", (data) => {
    string str = data.ToString();
    Car data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(str);
    addCar.AddNewCar(data2);
});
```

and then inside my `AddCar` class, I have the `AddNewCar()` method:

```
public void AddNewCar(Car input) {
    GameObject car = Instantiate(CarGameObject);
    car.transform.parent = this.transform;
    car.GetComponent<TestCar>().text.text = input.name;
}
```

it does not work. If I do a `Debug.Log(input.name)` inside the `AddNewCar()` method, it does log the name the server sends. It should do the exact same thing, but the `AddNewCar()` doesn't get added to the game. It simply does nothing.

What could be wrong?

Comment: How are you calling AddCar?

Comment: @AytAyt `addCar.AddNewCar(data2);`

Comment: Ok, my question is more, where did you put that line, and how do you call it. What is the script attached to?

Comment: Yeah, you aren't ever actually calling addCar as far as i can tell, which in turn means you aren't calling the AddNewCar method. Start is called automatically by Unity. You need to create something like: if (player input) is at (addCar button) then call AddNewCar. Or a timer or something.